# How can I export symbology and labels with QGIS Leaflet to webmap?

Tags: qgis, leaflet

If I make a map in QGIS export it with Leaflet the symbology and labels don't appear on the webmap. Is it possible to export them? If yes, how to export the all map?

Comment: Are you using qgis2leaf plugin? Have you reviewed the documentation on the github page? Did you select the 'extract labels' option? https://github.com/Geolicious/qgis2leaf

Comment: Try qgis2web instead. It is still being maintained and and developed, and its symbology and label features are getting better.